# After Change Evaporator had hissing sound from AC vent

Tags: ac, mitsubishi

I have Mitsubishi Outlander 2016, I have cooling complaint So, I took to garage the technician checked and said there is leakage in evaporator have to change.

After changed the evaporator while AC on cooling perfect after few minutes hissing sound coming from AC vent not continue few few minutes coming and going. For checking purpose switch off the AC that time no sound again switch on the AC the hissing sound coming this time I switch off AC mode hissing sound gone that means fan mode there is no issue while AC mode only hissing sound coming and going.

Kindly let me know exactly what is the issue and how to resolve.

Comment: I think this is vehicle-specific, some vehicles I have owned have made an audible hissing while the A/C was operating and some have not, I don't think it necessarily indicates a problem. If the system is cooling then I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

After you turn off the car, there will always be some "flow back" pressure adjustment within the Air Conditioning (AC) refrigerant system.  That hissing sound is absolutely normal for a few minutes after vehicle shut down in high temperatures.

Here's a graphic on the refrigerant system.

[image: graphic on refrigerant system]

On a really hot day, the pressure out of the compressor can be as high as 350 to 400 psi.  Normally, that hot gas enters the condenser where it cools down to a liquid.  The pressure on the low side of the evaporator will be in the 30 to 40 psi range.

When you shut the engine off, what do you think happens to that pressure differential?  Sure, it flows from high pressure to low pressure.  And when it does that a slight whistling or hissing sound is absolutely normal.

I would NOT assume the system is low on refrigerant charge. A hissing sound that lasts for a minute or two is totally normal.  I wouldn't go back to the repair shop.  That is just unnecessary.

Note: If the hissing sound continues for a really long time after shutdown, it is possible there is a refrigerant leak.  And if there is a leak, pretty soon, the refrigerant system will be inoperative.  No cooling.

Comment: +1 Many of my former vehicles would make intermittent hissing sounds while the air conditioner was operating (or after the engine was shut down). They were not low on refrigerant.

Answer (score 0):

Hissing in the passenger compartment linked to the AC will likely be caused by low refrigerant.

The expansion valve that is connected to the evaporator should have a constant feed of liquid refrigerant to operate correctly.  If the refrigerant is low then the hissing sound can come from gas getting to the expansion valve.

Take it back to the repair shop and get them to check it.  They may not have put enough refrigerant in when they repaired it.